self served vector tiles are not visible in react-map-gl
i am trying to get vector tiles served by martin (martin.maplibre.org) to be displayed in a react-map-gl application ( mapbox-gl)
this is what i do in the application:
<Source id="mySource" type="vector" url="http://0.0.0.0:3000/cityJsons">
        <Layer
          id="myLayer"
          type="line" // or "line", "symbol", "circle", "heatmap", "fill-extrusion", "raster", "hillshade" depending on your data and what you want to do
          source="mySource"
          source-layer="cityJsons"
          paint={{
            // add your paint styles here
            // for example:
            'line-color': '#888888',
            'line-opacity': 0.8,
          }}
        />
      </Source>

the tileset i am trying to use looks like this:
http://0.0.0.0:3000/catalog
{
  "tiles": {
    "cityJsons": {
      "content_type": "application/x-protobuf",
      "description": "cjdb.city_object.ground_geometry"
    }
  },
  "sprites": {

  },
  "fonts": {

  }
}

http://0.0.0.0:3000/cityJsons:
{
  "tilejson": "3.0.0",
  "tiles": [
    "http://0.0.0.0:3000/cityJsons/{z}/{x}/{y}"
  ],
  "vector_layers": [
    {
      "id": "cityJsons",
      "fields": {
        "attributes": "jsonb",
        "cj_metadata_id": "integer",
        "geometry": "jsonb",
        "object_id": "varchar",
        "type": "varchar"
      }
    }
  ],
  "bounds": [-180, -90, 180, 90],
  "description": "cjdb.city_object.ground_geometry",
  "maxzoom": 30,
  "minzoom": 0,
  "name": "cityJsons"
}

this is the martin config:

keep_alive: 75
listen_addresses: '0.0.0.0:3000'

base_path: /tiles
worker_processes: 8
cache_size_mb: 20000
preferred_encoding: brotli
postgres:
  connection_string: 'postgresql://postgres:postgrespw@localhost:5432/testcjdb'
  default_srid: 3857
  pool_size: 20
  max_feature_count: 100000
  auto_bounds: calc tables:
    cityJsons:
  
      layer_id: city_object 
      schema: cjdb 
      table: city_object 
      srid: 3857 
      geometry_column: ground_geometry 
      id_column: id 
      minzoom: 0 
      maxzoom: 30 
      bounds: [-180.0, -90.0, 180.0, 90.0] 
      extent: 4096 
      buffer: 64 
      clip_geom: true 
      geometry_type: MULTIPOLYGON 
      properties:
        object_id : varchar
        cj_metadata_id : integer
        attributes: jsonb
        type: varchar
        geometry : jsonb
  

Looking at the network tab and the console output of martin it does show that it downloads tiles correctly. but they are not shown in the map.
there are two things i am wondering:

Since these tiles are compressed, i am wondering if i miss something in the configuration? does react-map-gl knows automatically that these tiles are compressed?
since the files in the database are in EPSG:3857, is there some additional reprojecting necessary? Looking at the logs from martin it shows, that the geometry is exported directly without reprojection in 3857:

     SQL: SELECT
          ST_AsMVT(tile, 'city_object', 4096, 'geom', 'id')
        FROM (
          SELECT
            ST_AsMVTGeom(
                ST_Transform(ST_CurveToLine("ground_geometry"), 3857),
                ST_TileEnvelope($1::integer, $2::integer, $3::integer),
                4096, 64, true
            ) AS geom
            , "id", "attributes", "cj_metadata_id", "geometry", "object_id", "type"
          FROM
            "cjdb"."city_object"
          WHERE
            "ground_geometry" && ST_Transform(ST_TileEnvelope($1::integer, $2::integer, $3::integer, margin => 0.015625), 3857)
          LIMIT 100000
        ) AS tile; [16,34946,21789]

Thanks a lot for help!!
